# create multiple train, val, test splits using sample

Tags: r, tibble

I want to create train, val, test splits (60:20:20). I repeated the process multiple times.

1. Test set should contain only 2 observations each time. But why does it sometimes contain 1 or 3 observations.
2. What is role of replace in `sample()`. Should I keep it FALSE

```
library(dplyr)

tbl <- tibble(id = 1:10)

train = list()
val = list()
test = list()

for (run in 1:5)
{
  assignment <- sample(1:3, size = nrow(tbl), prob = c(0.6, 0.2, 0.2), replace = TRUE)
  
  # Create a train, validation and test sets
  train[[run]] <- tbl[assignment == 1, ] 
  val[[run]] <- tbl[assignment == 2, ]  
  test[[run]] <- tbl[assignment == 3, ]
}
```

Comment: You are not storing the output.  What is your expected output?  Is it just to answer those questions 1 and 2? i.e. the output of `train/val/test` will be the output from the last iteration

Comment: Hi @akrun, I have slightly modified the question

Comment: You can't keep it FALSE, as the `size` you mentioned is greater than the input length of vector 1:3

Comment: Do you need `split(tbl, sample(1:3, size = nrow(tbl), prob = c(0.6, 0.2, 0.2), replace = TRUE)
)`

Answer (score 1):

If we exactly 6, 2, 2, values for 1, 2, 3 as sample, just `rep`licate the 1, 2, 3 and `sample` it

```
v1 <- sample(rep(1:3, c(6, 2, 2)))
```

Then do a `split`

```
split(tbl, v1)
```

---

When we use `prob`, it can change the frequency slightly because it is just a probability.  Regarding the use of `replace = TRUE`, it is needed in the OP's code as the `length` of 1:3 is just 3, whereas `size = nrow(tbl)` is 10, thus without replacement, it can't fill those 7 extra elements